# Java XML Programming - Extracting the Child nodes

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have an xml file like below. I need to extract all the Child nodes under logdata and all the sub-Child nodes under each of the Child nodes along with their values. How can i extract these

```
<logdata>
    <Request RequestID="123" RequestType = "Read">
        <Data Mode = "Read">
            <Type>ReadWrite</Type>
        </Data>
        <Textdetails Eligible = "true">
            <Code>1</Code
            <Name>ABC</Name>
        </Textdetails>
    </Request>
    <Request RequestID="456" RequestType = "Read">
        <Data Mode = "Read">
            <Type>ReadWrite</Type>
        </Data>
        <Textdetails Eligible = "true">
            <Code>2</Code>
            <Name>DEF</Name>
        </Textdetails>
    </Request>
</logdata>
```

Comment: The built in SAX or DOM parser will do it.

Comment: Excellent.  Please read [ask] and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/  If you have a *specific* problem with your code at some point, then please post that.

Comment: The `<Code>1</Code` is missing a `>` at the end. The XML is invalid.

Comment: What do you want as an output?

Comment: I want the output in an excel file

Answer (score 0):

Using the [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/tutorial.xhtml) Library this would be rather simple. All you would need is to build the `Document` from a `Builder`. Then get the root element (`logdata`) using `getRootElement()`. After that you can use `getChildElements()` to get all the child elements from `logdata` and any other `Element`.